# How can I store data in an app that will be available even with login from another device?

Tags: android, web-services

I'm new with android apps developing. For now, I'm only capable to link the activities through buttons. For my app, I will need to know how to store user information so the same user can view his information even with a login from another device.

I saw in the official Android documentation the methods how data can be stored and the only one that seems to be useful in this case is Databases. How can I use this method (or another method to, if you know) for my aim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want data to be accessible from other devices, you need to store the data on a remote server and expose it through an API. Then in your Android app you would hit your API to pull down / store the user's data when needed. You could also store the data from the API locally in a MySQL database. If done correctly, this can help minimize network calls and maximize functionality when the network is not available. We can take a small example.

Let's say you have an app where the user just enters a number, and it gets stored on your backend + displayed in a TextView. Anytime the user logs in on any device, you want that user's number to appear in the textview.

Here is how you would do that: First have your user log in. This can be done with numerous frameworks. Once the user is logged in, you would check to see if that user already has a number stored in your backend. If so, you pull it down and display it on the textview. If not, you just display the blank textview. When the user enters a new number, you make a POST request to your API to tell it that this user wants to store a new number. Then this number would be stored and available on any device the user logs in on.

Comment: Except for the network availability problem, there are some other cons for the remote server approach? It seems to me the straight choice.

Comment: Not really. The network availability problem is something that all apps who store user data across sessions and devices struggle with. All you can do is put forth a best effort, use caching wisely, and hope your users have network. If users expect their data to persist across devices, they gotta have network these days.

Answer (score 0):

The remote server is a must for working with shared user data. For simple user data, however, I recommend a [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) RealTime database or [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) Firestore. 
You will save a lot of power.